# Is it possible to scaffold the controller and view with Visual Studio Code from Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I started using Visual Studio Code on my Mac. I am creating an ASP.Net MVC application. I was able to generate the app using **dotnet new -t web** pretty easily.

In the full version of the Visual Studio IDE, I was able to scaffold the controllers, views, and database schema very quickly using Entity Framework and Add Controller - MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework.

Is this possible in Visual Studio Code or from the terminal window on a Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have developed an extension for Visual Studio Code to handle this problem. :)
Using the `aspnet-generator` but I didn't upload it to the market, yet.

I will show you how to do it easily with one command line:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --project . controller -name YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME -m YOUR_MODEL_NAME -dc YOUR_DB_CONTEXT_CLASS -outDir Controllers/
```

Below is a sample :

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --project . controller -name ProductsController -m Product -dc ApplicationDbContext -outDir Controllers/
```

Here is a [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?ah11q3mwclm1f5y) to my under-development extension which you can use to scaffold your projects the same way like VS IDE do. :)

you need to extract the folder and move it to this location on your MAC:
`$HOME/.vscode/extensions`

then reload VS Code and it should work.

To Scaffold a `.NET CORE WEB Project` you need to press `cmd` + `shift` + `P` and choose `vscaff`.

It will ask you about your controller name and your model name assuming that your `DBcontext class` is `ApplicationDbContext` as provided by the dotnet new project template.

Good luck bro

Comment: is it also possible to use it on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @Micha93, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator for more information.